# Prestashop INVALID SECURITY TOKEN I understand the risks and I really want to display this page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Have created module which can create tab while installing it to prestashop v1.6 admin panel : to create tab and install code is as follow. please help to resolve.

```
 class Greeting extends Module {
   protected $tabs = [
    [
        'name' => 'Personalised Greetings',
        'className' => 'AdminMkonGreetinList',
        'active' => 1,
        'childs' => [
            [
                'active' => 0,
                'name' => 'List Greetings',
                'className' => 'AdminMkonGreetinList',
            ],
        ],
    ];

   //Adding Tab on Admin Section
    public function addTab($tabs, $id_parent = 0) {
    foreach ($tabs as $tab) {
        $tabModel = new Tab();
        $tabModel->module = $this->name;
        $tabModel->active = $tab['active'];
        $tabModel->class_name = $tab['className'];
        $tabModel->id_parent = $id_parent;

        //tab text in each language
        foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
            $tabModel->name[$lang['id_lang']] = $tab['name'];
        }

        $tabModel->add();

        //submenus of the tab
        if (isset($tab['childs']) && is_array($tab['childs'])) {
            $this->addTab($tab['childs'], 
            Tab::getIdFromClassName($tab['className']));
        }
    }
    return true;
  }
  public function __construct() {
     - - - - - -
  }
  public function install() {
    if (Shop::isFeatureActive()) {
        Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
    }
     //add Tabs
    $this->addTab($this->tabs);
      if (!parent::install() || !$this->registerHook('leftColumn') || 
    !$this->registerHook('header')) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->frontMenu();
    return true;
   }
  }
```

Dashboard Personalize Greetings Tab :
[image: Admin dashboard of Tab]

Error Screen while clicking on Tab :
[image: Error screen which came by clicking on tab]

Dashboard Personalize Greetings Tab :
Error Screen while clicking on Tab :

Comment: Is this happening when you make click on the option attached in the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is usually due to file(name) and class(name) case sensitive differences. also "controller" suffix is required

AdminMkonGreetinListController.php  :

```
Class AdminMkonGreetinListController extends ModuleAdminController
```